# load tab on click of radio button in AEM6

Tags: radio-button, aem

I have a couple of radio buttons in one my of tabs in the dialog and based on the radio button selected, I need to display the other tabs(i.e. tab2 or tab3) and initially my tab2 and tab3 will remain hidden.

I have achieved this using drop-down but now need to implement the same using radio buttons.

please help me on this
thanks in advance.

Comment: please show us some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you have got it to work with dropdown (selection xtype) already, setting **type** as **radio** should do it without any additional changes

Comment: thanks:Sharath Madappa

it works...never thought of such a small change.. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

**selection** xtype can be rendered as dropdown, combobox, checkboxes or radio buttons. So if you have already wriiten logic to hide and unhide tabs based on the value selected in the dropdown, simply adding **type** property with value **radio** (string) should ensure that the selection is rendred as radio buttons.